# Mapping Woocommerce order statuses using IF statements

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, orders

In Woocommerce, I am trying to map orders statuses with the following code:

```
function my_map_status ($status) {
    if ($status == "wc-processing") {
        return "WAA";
    } else {
        return $status;
    }
    if ($status == "wc-cancelled") {
        return "WAC";
    } else {
        return $status;
    }
}
```

But only the first one works.

How can I make it work for both?

Answer (score 0):

The first `IF` `ELSE` statement is taking every possibility. Instead use an `IF`  `ELSEIF`  `ELSE` structure:

```
function my_map_status ($status) {
    if ($status == "wc-processing") {
        return "WAA";
    } elseif ($status == "wc-cancelled") {
        return "WAC";
    } else {
        return $status;
    }
}
```

It should better work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not getting beyond the first `if` is that it has an `else` that just returns - so, if you think it through logically you will see that if $status is not wc-processing then return (and quit function) - in other words, it never gets beyond the first `if`.

Instead, you might like to consider using `switch/case`, which makes for much easier reading than multiple `if/elseif`s, like this:

```
switch ( $status ) {
    case "wc-processing":
        return "WAA";
        break;
    case "wc-cancelled":
        return "WAC";
        break;
    default:
        return $status;
}
```

*(in case you're wondering about the `break` - although not strictly necessary in this case (as the function will be exited with the `return`) it is good practice IMHO to always remember to use it every time you write a `switch` structure. More info on the page below.)*

Further reading: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php